# Filter Select (Drop Down) Options Based on Value Selected in another Select

Tags: javascript, api, filter, drop-down-menu

I have code below that is populating a select with values from the result array. - What I want to do is create an additional select that will filter the results based on the value {tag} selected.

For example:

I want the first select to only have the tags as options, based on the tag selected, the second select will only show names filtered by the selected tag.

I am also open to opinions on better ways to do this, for instance, if radio options work better for the filter then I would use those. - Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Snippet has been changed to include additional select with tag values. Just need to figure out how to make the second select change based on the tag selected in the first select.

```js
let result = [
  {name: "some name", tag: "some tag"},
  {name: "some name1", tag: "some tag1"},
  {name: "some name2", tag: "some tag2"},
  {name: "some name2-2", tag: "some tag2"}
];

let hcList = document.getElementById("hclist");
Object.keys(result).map((key) => hcList.add(new Option(result[key].name, JSON.stringify(result[key]))));

    let uniqueTags = [...new Set(result.map((item) => item.tag))];

    let tagList = document.getElementById("taglist");
    Object.keys(uniqueTags).map((key) =>
      tagList.add(new Option(uniqueTags[key]))
    );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<select id="taglist"></select>
  <select id="hclist"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this. I have added comments wherever necessary:

```js
let result = [
  {name: "some name", tag: "some tag"},
  {name: "some name1", tag: "some tag1"},
  {name: "some name2", tag: "some tag2"},
  {name: "some name2-2", tag: "some tag2"}
];

//Generic function to fill a dropdown with options 
let populateDropDown = (params) => {
    params.optionsToPopulate.forEach(item => {
        params.ddlElement.add(new Option(item[`${params.text}`], item[`${params.text}`]))
    })
}

//Initialize tags dropdown
(function(){
  document.getElementById("tagsDdl").addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    tagChanged(event);
  });

    let params = {
        optionsToPopulate:result,
        ddlElement:document.getElementById("tagsDdl"),
        id:"tag",
        text:"tag"
    }
    populateDropDown(params);

    //Uncomment the below code if you want to set names dropdown on page load based on the value of tags dropdown on pageload
    /*  let paramsNames = {
            optionsToPopulate:result.filter(item => item.tag === document.getElementById("tagsDdl").value),
            ddlElement:document.getElementById("namesDdl"),
            id:"name",
            text:"name"
        }
        populateDropDown(paramsNames);*/

})();

//Tags dropdown change event.
let tagChanged = (event) => {   
    let tagDdlValue = event.target.value;

    //filter the results based on the value of tags dropdonw
    let optionsToAdd = result.filter(item => item.tag === tagDdlValue);
    let namesDdl = document.getElementById("namesDdl");
    namesDdl.options.length=0;
    let params = {
        optionsToPopulate:optionsToAdd,
        ddlElement:namesDdl,
        id:"name",
        text:"name"
    }   
    populateDropDown(params);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  Tags DDL: <select id="tagsDdl"></select> 

  <br><br><br>
  Names DDL: <select id="namesDdl"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems like the answer I am looking for. - I'm currently testing in my dev environment but whenever the onChange event tries to use the tagChanged function it's giving me the following error - "tagChanged is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange." I believe this is due to my JS file being separate from my HTML file but not sure why since it seems as if tagChanged is declared as global. I'd be happy to mark this as the correct answer but want this issue to be resolved before doing so. Any opinion here? Thanks!

Comment: @Dr.Tenma If your javascript code is in a different file add a script tag with src equal to path of the file. For example: if I have my javascript is in a file index.js my script tag would look like: ``<script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js" ></script>``. Place the script tag just above the body closing tag ``</body>``

Comment: Thanks, I already have this configured. Using your code the page currently populates the tag drop down but still gives the error  "tagChanged is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange." and the name list does not populate.

Comment: @Dr.Tenma Interesting. Looking at the error ``tagChanged is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange.``, I would once try to change the case of onchange function at the tagsDdl select element. So the previous ``<select onChange = "tagChanged(event)" id="tagsDdl"></select>`` would be changed to ``<select onchange = "tagChanged(event)" id="tagsDdl"></select> ``

Comment: @Dr.Tenma Try adding the change event by ``addEventListener``. I have updated the js part of the code in the answer to do the same. Also, remove onchange event from HTML. It runs on my side. By the way, what browser you are testing in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218315/discussion-between-ravi-and-dr-tenma).

Answer (score 1):

U can use **JQuery** to achieve that easily. with $element.change() - every time u change the first select.selectedValue -> u can refresh and update the second select.

```
 $('#hclist').change(function(){
       refreshSecondSelect($(this).val());
    });
```

see example: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/gzxe2fyk/)

Comment: Thanks @Evya2005 - I can see how this works, however, I am looking for an answer that uses vanilla JS. Do you have another solution that doesn't use JQuery?

Comment: Hi Evya... a great answer, however if my select options have `<option value="whatever1">whatever</option>` property. I tried your JSfiddle example by adding "value=" in your options and it breaks, not populating the second select. I need to filter mine on "value" instead of option text. I know this is easy for you :), I"m more a PHP dev. Thank you.

Comment: Evya.. I did figure it out. I changed any JS reference from `.text` to `.val`. Thank you. I have upticked you.